# How to delete any page from pdf using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I'm trying to remove a blank page from the pdf document using VBA but there is some issue occuring...

```
> Sub deletepage()

A as acrobat.acroapp

B as acrobat.acropddoc

Set a = createobject("acroexch.app")

Set b = createobject("acroexch.pddoc")

A.show

Myfoc.open(filename)

If mydoc.deletepages(1,2)=True then

Deleted

Else

Not deleted

End if

> End sub
```

Comment: What is the link to Excel?

Comment: "some" issue? What is the issue you are seeing? An error message? Your code is definitely incomplete but please start helping yourself by analysing the issue and providing more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Python in combination with VBA, you might try this:

```
Sub DeletePageFromPDF()
    Dim RetVal As Long
    ' Call the Python script to delete the 3rd page from the PDF file
    RetVal = Shell("python.exe C:\python\delete_page.py C:\TEST\test.pdf 3", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Python Script 'delete_page.py':

```
import sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

def delete_page(file_path, page_number):
    pdf = PdfReader(file_path)
    #pdf.getPage(page_number).expand_objects()
    #pdf.getPage[page_number]
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()

    # Loop through all pages in the PDF file
    for i in range(len(pdf.pages)):
        # Skip the page to be deleted
        if i != page_number - 1:
            pdf_writer.add_page(pdf.pages[i])

    # Write the updated PDF file
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
        pdf_writer.write(f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_path = sys.argv[1]
    page_number = int(sys.argv[2])
    delete_page(file_path, page_number)
```

But you need to have python on your system. I'm just starting with Python myself and find it a good "expansion" for things that get complicated in VBA.

Give it a try.

Regards